# why my sign up page don't work even i enter my fire base code correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

when i try to sign up this error appear

> this.props.firebase.signupwithemail is not a function.(In'_this.props.firebase.signupWithEmail(email,password)',
>   '_this.props.firebase.signupWithEmail'is undefined)

that's my code

```
handleOnSignup = async (values, actions) => {
const { name, email, password } = values

try {
  const response = await this.props.firebase.signupWithEmail(
    email,
    password
  )

  if (response.user.uid) {
    const { uid } = response.user
    const userData = { email, name, uid }
    await this.props.firebase.createNewUser(userData)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
  }
} catch (error) {
  // console.error(error)
  actions.setFieldError('general', error.message)
} finally {
  actions.setSubmitting(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.props.firebase.signInWithEmail
```

into this:

```
this.props.firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword
```

Comment: i correct the code as you said and the same error appear   with a little change this.props.firebase.signupwithemailAndPassword is not a function.(In'_this.props.firebase.signupWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)', '_this.props.firebase.signupWithEmailAndPassword'is undefined)

Comment: @kimitch `this.props.firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)`